# WebSocket API Connection issue

Tags: html, api, cakephp, websocket

I suppose I'm havin' a beginner's problem regarding websocket connection.

Here's the thing, I'm researching on using websocket and I followed this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebSocketTest()
{
  if ("WebSocket" in window)
  {
     alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
     // Let us open a web socket
     var ws = new WebSocket("ws://172.16.0.195:8080/echo");
     ws.onopen = function()
     {
        // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
        ws.send("Message to send");
        alert("Message is sent...");
     };
     ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
     { 
        var received_msg = evt.data;
        alert("Message is received...");
     };
     ws.onclose = function()
     { 
        // websocket is closed.
        alert("Connection is closed..."); 
     };
  }
  else
  {
     // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
     alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sse">
   <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

... which I copied from the internet. When I tested it, Firefox said that my browser supports websocket feature but it DOESN'T ESTABLISH CONNECTION TO MY SERVER. I try to telnet our server in port 80 and I could gain connection to it. But if I am to use websocket connection in my page,it does not establish connection anymore.

Thank you very much in advance for any inputs/help.

[EDIT]
** by the way, does ".../echo" in my specified websocket connection has to do something with it? I mean, do I have to have some echo.php in my server?

Comment: Yes, as you suspect, you need to have some sort of server-side script constantly running on your server, listening for socket connections. Without that, WebSocket cannot establish a connection.

Comment: Thanks much. I just figured it out just now. >.<  crazy me  :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial helped me a lot:

[Getting started with HTML5′s Web Sockets](http://wickedlysmart.com/getting-started-with-html5s-web-sockets/)

Now I have my server set up already.